# MSI Intaller: Doesn't insert a DLL on the GAC

Tags: windows-installer, gac

I have a problem with a MSI Installer. I cannot figure out why it is not inserting some DLL on the client's GAC.

This is the assembly info

[image]

The assembly is signed
[image]

The MSI Installer, is correctly configured to install the DLL on the GAC
[image]

However, after building and running the Installer, the dll isn't on the gac folder: C:\Windows\assembly (The picture is ordered by name.)

[image]

Also I tried to find it by cmd
[image]

Comment: You are just looking the wrong place.  .NET 4.x assemblies are stored in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  It doesn't have the shell extension that hides the files, you can navigate the folder structure directly with Explorer.  Not particularly complicated, start at GAC_MSIL unless it is a mixed-mode assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant That was exactly the problem. Thanks ^^